# Flat Catalog Product rebuild error in magento 1.3

Tags: indexing, flat-catalog, magento-1.3

Can any one help me to solve this error https://prnt.sc/omfwt3
I am getting this error when i try to Rebuild Flat Catalog Product in magento 1.3

Comment: You have defined `Magento 1.3` in the Question title and in the description it's 2.3. please mention your Magento version properly.

Comment: @MohitRane i am sorry.. its magento 1.3. I edited my question